# Many to many relationship using spring boot and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, many-to-many

I am new to spring boot technology.

I have a problem, how to map many to many relationships using spring boot when passed the `objectId` of another collection and retrieve the details of that object too.

Ex:
There are two models named `Vehicles` & `Categories`. When creating a new vehicle type we can pass the `Category Id` like below.

[image]

When retrieving the `Vehicle` should display like this.

[image]

This example developed using node.js and express.js.

Like that way how I can do that for spring boot. I tried with `@JoinColumns`, `@DBRef` and none of them doesn't work for me.

Here are my models.

**Vehicle model**

```
    @Document(collection = "Vehicle")
    public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private List<Category> categoryList;

   //getters and setters go here
```

**Category model**

```
@Document(collection = "Category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Double amount;

//getters and setters go here
```

It's better if you can tell me the way of implementing the Controller and Service or Repository according to this.

***Thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 0):

can't help you with spring-boot stuff but you need to do a `$lookup` operation to join the foreign documents using the mongodb driver you're using.

the following is how it's done using mongo shell:

```
db.Vehicle.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { _id: "vehicle-id" } },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Category",
                localField: "categories._id",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "categories"
            }
        }
    ])
```

see it in action here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/OgXrAxE2uXu

ගුඩ් ලක්‌!